# how to convert large xml files to csv format?

Tags: xml, csv

I tried it online but the size is too big.
i want to convert large xml files nearly 50 mb to csv format which is unable to be done at all neither online nor in any software.
i wanna know what should be the best idea to convert them thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: 50mb is not particularly large these days and it shouldn't require any special treatment. This is a routine task, which many people would tackle without difficulty using XSLT. You need to show us what you tried and how it failed, and then we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: XML documents, cannot, in the general case, be expressed as CSV. Take [this XML](https://www.svgrepo.com/download/530620/wine.svg) for example, that is not a 2-d data structure. In some specific cases you could do a conversion, but we know nothing about your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a standard format for content.  I would approach this as two steps. Google "parse xml" and "generate csv". Your program will implement both and then you'll be done. There are a number of options.

Also, consider using a program that reads XML files and uses XSLT files to do the transformation.  If you pop over to W3schools there is a tutorial about XML and XLST: 
[w3schools xsl tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp).  The XSL usually is used to generate HTML from an XML file, but an HTML file is just text.  You could output the CSV directly. (There are some issues with CSV that cause some headaches, such as punctuation including commas and double quotes that can mess up the CSV, but there are workarounds.

This snippet is an example of generating a two column CSV file pulling out Title and Artist from an XML file containing those tags.  The second line is the header line for CSV and the rest of the template forms each subsequent line in the CSV file:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
Title,Artist\n
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>,<xsl:value-of select="artist"/>\n
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The \n imbedded in the template needs to be whatever is the new line character in the processor you choose.  Substitute the correct tag names for your application. The Saxan and Xalan are two projects that implement the process. XSLTproc [XSLTproc is available here](http://xmlsoft.org/) is a command line tool. If you do this in a browser you could implement the html table syntax from the example at w3schools.

Answer (score -1):

Check [conversiontools.io](https://conversiontools.io).

[Online XML to CSV Converter](https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-csv) that supports conversion of XML files up to **10MB**.

The 10MB XML can be converted using their [XML to Excel Converter](https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-excel), and it will split the result into several .xlsx files based on the Excel limits (number of rows limit).
You need to register or purchase a plan if the file size is more than 10MB (after registration the limit is 20MB, and paid plans work for 100GB+ files).